# Android YouTube get user playlists

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I am using this code to get the token:

```
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(GuiManager.getMainActivity(), email, scope);
```

The email is the user email scope is : `oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`

And then i want to get the user playlists with this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&mine=true&maxResults=50&fields=items/id,items/snippet/title&key=DEVELOPER_KEY&access_token=token
```

And with this code:

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get(playlistUrl, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,byte[] response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
             GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(GuiManager.getMainActivity(), token);
             token = "";
             token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(GuiManager.getMainActivity(), email, scope);
             //Try load playlist again Function
        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            // called when request is retried
        }
    });
```

And i get :
Status code 401. and :`error=invalid_token`

Any idea what is broken with my code? 
In iPhone i am using `secretid` and `clientid` fo the `Google` login, here i can see i am only need the scope and the user email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use GoogleAccountCredential instead of GoogleAuthUtil.
Here's a sample app using it: https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java